# hotkey copy-paste functionality in Properties window while developing Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, copy-paste, hotkeys

I'm working with Eclipse Helios on Android app and found that when constructing UI I'm not able to use common Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V. Using RMB+Paste works fine. However I'm also not able to paste using Eclipse menu -> Edit, where "Paste" is just disabled.

Please advice..

Answer (score 0):

I'm also developing in Eclipse Helios, i just use RMB+Coby and RMB+Paste ? 
But when you should paste something in again, you need to RMB the view where the copied items should go..

Does that work for you ?

Comment: heh, no, I just do not want to use Right Mouse Button. I want to use hot keys :)